# Magento 2 : PDF print invoice logo position change

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

I want to change the position of the logo in the PDF print invoice logo.

I have to use Magento ver. 2.4.1

please help me

thanks

[image]

Comment: is this from frontend or admin side?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, this is backend (admin panel)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a preference on the following class wherever you want.

```
class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice{
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,\Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem, Config $pdfConfig, Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory, ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate, \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation, \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        parent::__construct($paymentData, $string, $scopeConfig, $filesystem, $pdfConfig, 
        $pdfTotalFactory, $pdfItemsFactory, $localeDate, $inlineTranslation, 
        $addressRenderer, $storeManager, $appEmulation, $data);
    }
```

Then all you have to do is to rewrite the protected function `_drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)` method

Then you call create a custom logo anywhere you want

```
protected function insertLogo(&$page, $store = null)
{
    //ADAPT THE POSITION
    $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
    $image = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'sales/identity/logo',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $store
    );
    if ($image) {
        //ADAPT THE PATH
        $imagePath = '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;
        if ($this->_mediaDirectory->isFile($imagePath)) {
            $image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagePath));
            $top = 830;
            //top border of the page
            $widthLimit = 200;
            //half of the page width
            $heightLimit = 50;
            //assuming the image is not a "skyscraper"
            $width = $image->getPixelWidth();
            $height = $image->getPixelHeight();

            //preserving aspect ratio (proportions)
            $ratio = $width / $height;
            if ($ratio > 1 && $width > $widthLimit) {
                $width = $widthLimit;
                $height = $width / $ratio;
            } elseif ($ratio < 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                $height = $heightLimit;
                $width = $height * $ratio;
            } elseif ($ratio == 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                $height = $heightLimit;
                $width = $widthLimit;
            }

            $y1 = $top - $height;
            $y2 = $top;
            $x1 = 25;
            $x2 = $x1 + $width;

            //coordinates after transformation are rounded by Zend
            $page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);

            $this->y = $y1 - 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answers, i have used your bit of code with different logic, but yes help full code